# Why are some ISO files not mountable via Supermicro iKVM Viewer

Tags: java, ipmi, supermicro, iso

I am using a Supermicro server, and its ipmi firmware has a so called "Virtual Media" function. It allows you to mount an ISO file, which is then presented to server as a USB CD-ROM.

I cannot understand why some of the ISO files are not mountable. When I choose an ISO file in Virtual Storage menu, and then click Plug in button, I got message:

> Device1: Can not open ISO Image File

But some other ISO files are able to be mounted correctly with the message:

> Device1: VM Plug-In OK!!

I thought that the ISO file size could be a problem, but seems it is not.

Edit: there is a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/907394/unable-to-mount-iso-virtual-media-over-ipmi-ikvm-viewer), but in that case the cause was firewall.

Answer (score 2):

It is the problem of java iKVM Viewer. It for some reason requires a write permission to your iso file. If it is missing, then mounting fails.

I have accidentally found mentioning of such requirement from the very end of [this](https://www.mcgill.org.za/stuff/archives/340) article.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I noticed on the iso's that would not mount, I was not the owner like the other files.  Once I changed ownership I was able to mount them.